# How to include href in const and export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am importing all the constants for my application from a single constant.js file.

```
export const ERR_DOB = "Enter your Date of birth"
```

I wish to add href in the that constant.

For eg:

```
export const txt = Click <a href="index.html">Here!<a>
```

But this not working as expected. 
Printing the same

```
"Click <a href='index.html'>Here!</a>"
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `const` or `export`, and everything with how you are using the string value. Which is in the part of your code that you unfortunately haven't shown us.

Comment: I want to display my const txt as Click Here! with href. I am getting the html code as such. If I export as export const txt = Click ${<a href="index.html">Here!<a>}, displaying as Click [Object object]

Comment: This is your best (enemy / friend): https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Would highly NOT recommend that approach though. Can you think of creating a component which can create hyperlinks from your constants?

Comment: btw, are you trying to implement "internationalization" by any chance? If yes, there might be better solutions out there that I can recommend.

Comment: @dubes Yes. I am trying to implement "Internationalization"

Answer (score 0):

with react, you can not just set innerHtml like that, the proper way to fix is to render children of your react virtual DOM.
Or, you can use

```
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: your html code }}
```

https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are trying for internationalization, if you are not open to use any other library, then `dangerourslySetInnterHTML` is the only way to go ([see official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml))

But internationalization has many other use cases which may not easy to be handled by home grown solution (plurals, contenxtual translations etc.), for this I personally use and recommend: react-i18next ([website](https://react.i18next.com/))

Your case where you want to use `anchor` tags, the `Trans Component` of the library will come handy.

To internationalize

```
Click <a href='index.html'>Here!</a>
```

You will have to wrap it within the Trans component:

```
<Trans i18nKey="myHref">
    Click <a href='index.html'>Here!</a>
</Trans>
```

Your translation will look like:

```
"myHref": "Click <1><0>Here!</1>,
```

To change it to some other message, you will not have to change your code, just change the dictionary:

```
"myHref": "Please <1><0>click here</1>,
```

Do look through their official site. They have decent documentation and also host examples on their github repo.

Comment: Pleasure! If the answer helped, please do accept & upvote so that it is helpful for others in  future. I am here if you have any follow up questions.